# Git Unsupported proxy syntax

Tags: git, github, proxy

I'm using a corporate laptop and I'm trying to push my project into the distant git repository. I first had a " Could not resolve host : github.corporatenamecloud.com " So I tried to set the proxy settings in git config with the command :

git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port

But now I get a "Unsupported proxy syntax".
I tried to convert for example the char "*" in my password to it URL encoding reference and "-" in the proxy name but nothing did the job. What can be the problem ?

Comment: Are there any other characters other than `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `+`, and `-` in your password?  If so, it's probably most prudent to escape those as well.  However, you should _not_ escape dashes in hostnames.  Can you show us an example of the syntax you used to escape it?

Comment: So I don't need to escape "-" ? The command I used is like this : git config --global http.proxy http://proxyusername:pwd%2A@http://xx-xxxx-xx.xxxx.com:8080 . I have a "*" in my pwd so I replaced it with "%2A". Is this correct ?

Comment: Dashes don't require escaping in URLs.  `%2A` is correct for an asterisk.